# Set default Xcode 6 preview devices

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, uistoryboard, preview

Is there any way to set the default preview choices (devices) in "Assistant Editor > Preview" in Xcode 6?
I'm working with 6.1.1

For example, I usually want to see previews for all iPhones in portrait (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8xbq.png)

Any time I change between my storyboard and other source files (with the project explorer), I lose all the previews I've previously chosen.

Thanks!